# Screen height and width in a View

Tags: android, height, width, deprecated

I'm getting a "The method getHeight() from the type Display is deprecated" error when trying to get the Height and Width of the screen size, code:

```
public JumpboyView(MyView mv, Context contextPlay) {
    super(contextPlay);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    bBoy = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.boy);

    Display display = ((WindowManager) contextPlay.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    height = display.getHeight();
```

and when trying to use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);`

I get "The method getWindowManager() is undefined for the type JumpboyView" with 2 fixes available change to getWindowToken() or create method..

Help please?

p.s it used to work on older versions :\

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/181714) answer. it explains how and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) contextPlay.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    height = size.y
```

Comment: display.getSize(size) you mean?
seems to work with no erros, but my app doesn't seem to work for other reasons now, since that one is already fixed, I'll see what's next.
Thanks!

Comment: weird...It used to work with older versions, now with only this error and hopefully its fixed right, app "Unfortunately stops working"..